# wxWidgets wrong substring

Tags: substring, wxwidgets

I am trying to extract a substring out of some html code in wxWidgets but I can't get my method working properly.

content of to_parse:

[HTML CODE]

```
<html><head></head><body><font face="Segue UI" size=2 .....<font face="Segoe UI"size="2" color="#000FFF"><font face="@DFKai-SB" ... <b><u> the text </u></b></font></font></font></body></html>
```

[/HTML CODE]    (sorry about the format)

```
wxString to_parse = SOStream.GetString();

size_t spos = to_parse.find_last_of("<font face=",wxString::npos);
size_t epos = to_parse.find_first_of("</font>",wxString::npos);

wxString retstring(to_parse.Mid(spos,epos));
wxMessageBox(retstring);    // Output: always --->  tml>
```

As there are several font face tags in the HTML the to_parse variable I would like to find the postion of the last `<"font face=` and the postion of the first `<"/font>"` close tag.

For some reason, only get the same *to me unexpected*  output    `tml>`

Can anyone spot the reason why?

Answer (score 0):

The methods `find_{last,first}_of()` don't do what you seem to think they do, they behave in the same way as `std::basic_string<>` methods of the same name and find the first (or last) character of the string you pass to them, see [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of).

If you want to search for a substring, use `find()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer. Yes you were right, I must have somehow been under the impression that Substring() / substr() / Mid() takes two wxStrings as parameters, which isn't the case.

```
wxString to_parse = SOStream.GetString();

to_parse = to_parse.Mid(to_parse.find("<p "));   disregarts everything before "<p "
to_parse = to_parse.Remove(to_parse.find("</p>"));  removes everything after "</p>"

wxMessageBox(to_parse);  // so we are left with everything between "<p"  and  "</p>"
```